# Delta Query on group taking multiple calls to return users in a group

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I tried running delta query to select ONLY members of a group containing 3 users using the below code:

```
var delta = await _graphServiceClient.Groups
.Delta()
.Request()
.Select("members")
.Filter($"id eq '{groupId}'")
.GetAsync();
```

and I see a total of 36 delta calls (36 pages using next link) to read the users from the group. On running the delta query on graph explorer, I see the data returned in 2 calls (2 pages). Why is that? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

To get the **Azure AD Group members** using delta query, try the below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$filter=id+eq+'GroupID'&$expand=members
```

[image]

**To get the results via **`c#`** SDK, please try the below code snippet:**

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var delta = await graphClient.Groups
.Delta()
.Request()
.Filter("id eq 'GroupID'")
.Expand("members")
.GetAsync();
```

To get the **members of the Azure AD group**, try the below query:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupID?$expand=members
```

[image]

**To get the results via **`c#`** SDK, try the below code snippet:**

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var  group = await graphClient.Groups["GroupID"]
.Request()
.Expand("members")
.GetAsync();
```

**UPDATE:**

If I use **`$select=members`**, then it returns only the members of the Group like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$filter=id+eq+'GroupID'&$select=members
```

[image]

If I use **`$expand=members`**, then it returns the members of the Group with Group Properties like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$filter=id+eq+'GroupID'&$expand=members
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference between expand and select?

Comment: But @user989988 question is related to delta query and you suggest not to use delta at all? user989988 is using select because he wants to return only members not all properties. Using expand=members doesn't have any effect because members is not relationship.

Comment: Agree with @user2250152 the reason why I used $select is to only select members not any other properties. Consider a group with large number of users (900k users) the api would take a long time to return the response.

Comment: Hi @user989988 Please check the updated answer where I have shown the output difference between `expand` and `select` attributes in the delta query. Kindly let me know if you have more queries regarding this.

Comment: Thank you! My question is regarding c# code. With $select why I see so many calls?

Comment: using $expand=members doesn't have any effect. members are returned by default. Can you explain why do you still use $expand=members? Try the query without expand and you will see that member are always part of the response.

Comment: @user2250152 I don't use $expand. I use $select to select only members and I was hoping that would reduce the number of calls to read the group membership. But, that doesn't happen.

Comment: @user2250152 I use application permission to use this delta api. I wonder if that is causing more number of calls.